# Lower bound for the degree of $f^3 - g^2$ using Mason's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $f, g \in K[t]$ non-constant such that $ f^3 - g^2 \not = 0$, and let $h=f^3 - g^2$. Show that $\deg(f) \le 2\deg(h) - 2$ and $\deg(g) \le 3\deg(h) - 3$.

Alright, I know that this should ideally be just an application of the Mason-Stothers Theorem, which states that $\max(\deg(f), \deg(g), \deg(h)) \le \deg(rad(fgh)) -1 $ for any coprime polynomials $f, g, h$ belonging to the polynomial ring of a field with characteristic $0$, satisfying the relation $ f+g=h$, but for some reason, I find myself in a bit of a cerebral rut.

Could anybody give me a heads up on how to go about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We will suppose that $f$, $g$ and $h$ are coprime.

Note that $F+G=H$, where $F=f^3$, $G=-g^2$ and $H=h$. Thus, the Mason-Stothers theorem implies that
$$
\max\{\deg F,\deg G,\deg H\}\le\deg(\operatorname{rad}(FGH))-1\le\deg(fgh)-1=
\\
=\deg f+\deg g+\deg h.
$$
In other words,
$$
\max\{3\deg f,2\deg g,\deg h\}\le \deg f+\deg g+\deg h-1.
$$
Hence,
$$
\deg f+\deg g+\deg h-1\ge\frac{1}{2}(3\deg f+2\deg g),~\text{or}~\deg f\le 2\deg h-2
$$
and similarly
$$
\deg f+\deg g+\deg h-1\ge\frac{1}{3}(3\deg f+2\cdot2\deg g),~\text{or}~\deg g\le 3\deg h-3.
$$

**Comment**. This is also known as Davenport's theorem. See H. Davenport (1965), On Norske Vid. Selsk. Forrh. 38, pp. 86-87.